# Sphere with one squared corner

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to replicate this logo to 3d space but I'm not able to make the last green portion.[image]

Here is an image of the intended result :
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get close with proportional editing.

1. Add a UV sphere and rotate it 45° in edit mode
2. Grab the top point and align it to the top right corner
3. Check ✓ *Proportional Editing > Sharp*, adjust Falloff so it fits

[image]

Comment: You're quick off the mark, today, JM  :D

Comment: Hahah, I should probably get a life. But not today :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way.. (Pivot set to '3D Cursor', Orientation 'Local'):

1. Rotate your ref by 45, and align a sphere to it, poles up and down. Put the Cursor at its center. (I did mine in Edit mode, so I had to reposition the origin of the sphere to the cursor:

[image]

2. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (Local) extend the pole vertex to the reference's point. You may need to rotate the geometry to get a match all round.

[image]

3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> - select a few edge loops, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> dissolve them

[image]

4. After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevelling the pole vertex a fraction, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> replace the loops.

[image]

You may need to do a *tiny* bit of vertex-smoothing, edge-sliding..

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution. It's more "mathematically precise" but requires a few more steps.

1. Start with a plane.
2. Bevel all but 1 corner (cmd+shift+B).

   - Tap V to affect vertices instead of edges if it's not already.
   - Tap C to use clamping so the size of each bevel uses exactly half of the edge length.
   - Make sure you use an EVEN number of segments (scroll wheel or S+mouse to change) so there is a single vertex at the opposite end of the non-beveled vertex.

[image: Bevel all but one vertex]

3. There will be 2 overlapping vertices. Use merge by distance to remove them.

[image: Merge vertices]

4. Remove vertices using dissolve until the shape is half the shape it was before.

[image: Dissolve vertices]

5. Drop an empty and rotate it by 45deg on the Z-axis.

[image: Place an empty]

6. Apply a Screw modifier to the plane.

   - Set the axis to Y or X (depending on which vertex wasn't beveled)
   - Set Axis Object to the Empty.
   - Make sure you check the "Merge" option to get a clean result.

[image: Apply screw modifier]

Optional: Apply the Screw modifier to permanently set the solid.

Unedited video version:
https://youtu.be/tOCXQz4tehE

Comment: Neat. Could you not just delete the pole-to-pole straight edge, (and the internal face) before screwing?

Comment: @RobinBetts you could, but you don't need to. The edge is automatically deleted when the screw happens.

Comment: ..thanks! I never knew that.